# How to display the images in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

[These are the list of pictures i want from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rg2M.png)I have a firebase database from where iam getting a list of lmages and out it in recyclerview. Iam able to get the url of all the images but i cannot display the images in my imageview.

```
 private void getImagesFromDatabase() {
    Log.d("hh", "Reach Here");
    //   String  USERID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();

    final DatabaseReference historyDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("BeautyCenters").child(nameofspa).child("Images");
    historyDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot pictures : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("SPAA", "pictures  ARE" + pictures);
                Log.d("SPAA", "data  ARE " + dataSnapshot);
                ImagesObject imagesObject = pictures.getValue(ImagesObject.class);
                uploads.add(imagesObject);
            }
            imagesAdapter = new ImagesAdapter(DetailsPage.this, uploads);
            logorecylerview.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);
}
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried this code but this is giving me error as     com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type .DetailsPage.ImagesObject.

This is my ADPATER CLASS

```
public class ImagesAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<ImagesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<ImagesObject> mUploads;
    private Context mcontext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ImagesAdapter.ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    public ImagesAdapter(Context context, List<ImagesObject> uploads) {
       this. mcontext = context;
       this. mUploads = uploads;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);

        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.picturesofspa, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ImagesObject imagesObject = mUploads.get(position);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(imagesObject.getImages())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.testsaloon)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .into(holder.PicturesofSPA);

    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ImageView PicturesofSPA;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            PicturesofSPA = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PicturesofSPA);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return  this.mUploads.size();
    }
}
```

This is my object class:

```
public class ImagesObject {
    private String Images;

    public ImagesObject(String Images) {
        this.Images = Images;
    }

public ImagesObject() {
}
    //Images
    public String getImages(){
        return Images;
    }
    public void setImages(String Images)
    {
        this.Images = Images;
    }
}
```

This is where I am getting the URL from:

```
private List<ImagesObject> uploads;
        uploads = new ArrayList<>();

 private void getImagesFromDatabase() {
        Log.d("hh", "Reach Here");
        //   String  USERID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();

        final DatabaseReference historyDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("BeautyCenters").child(nameofspa).child("Images");
        historyDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot pictures : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("SPAA", "pictures  ARE" + pictures);
                    Log.d("SPAA", "data  ARE " + dataSnapshot);

                    ImagesObject imagesObject = pictures.getValue(ImagesObject.class);
                    uploads.add(imagesObject);
                }
                imagesAdapter = new ImagesAdapter(DetailsPage.this, uploads);
                logorecylerview.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);
    }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

With this code, it is giving me the count of pictures but not showing any pictures"

```
for (DataSnapshot pictures : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("SPAA", "pictures  ARE" + pictures);
                Log.d("SPAA", "data  ARE " + dataSnapshot);

                ImagesObject imagesObject = dataSnapshot.getValue(ImagesObject.class);
                uploads.add(imagesObject);
            }
```

Comment: Override getItemCount() method and return the size of mUpload list.

Comment: im already doing it in Adapter class

Comment: @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return  this.mUploads.size();
    }
}

Comment: @AyeshaIsrar review the edits proposed by someone and act on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type .DetailsPage.ImagesObject
```

You are getting the above error because in your database image url are store as string.

Your database is like

```
Images:
       l0: url1
       l1: url2
       l2: url3
```

It should be of class ImagesObject type like below

```
Images:
      l0:
         Images: url1
      l1:
         Images: url2
      l2:
         Images: url3
```

In order to avoid the error, try below 2 solutions:

1. Push image urls into your real time database using ImagesObject class or make your database like above.

or

2. Do this in your code.

```
String url = pictures.getValue(String.class);
ImagesObject imgObject = new ImagesObject(url);
uploads.add(imgObject);
```

Moreover, avoid setting adapter inside `valueEventListener`. Set adapter outside and use `notifyDataSetChanged` when list upload changes.
Also do not make String Images inside ImagesObject private.

Comment: If anyone has queries or can improve the answer, please do comment.